# Properties of an R-bimodule which force R to be a simple ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be a unital and associative ring (not necessarily commutative) and let $R$ be a subring of $M$ such that $1_M \in R$.

Moreover, suppose that $I$ is an index set (possibly infinite) and that $M = \oplus_{i\in I} N_i$, where $N_i$ is an $R$-submodule of $M$ for each $i\in I$ and that $N_j=R$ for some $j\in I$.

Define a map $\Psi$ from $2^I$ to the set of all equivalence classes of $R$-bimodules which are contained in $M$, by the following:

$I \supseteq J \stackrel{\Psi}{\longmapsto} [\oplus_{j\in J} N_j$]

(Here we map $\emptyset$ to the zero-module {0}.)

Question:
Suppose that $\Psi$ is a bijection. Is $R$ necessarily a simple ring?

I am unable to construct a counterexample and I am also not able to prove it. The case $|I|=1$ is trivial, but not even the case $|I|=2$ is completely clear to me.

An obvious observation:
By the assumption that $\Psi$ is a bijection, we get $N_i \cong N_j$ (as $R$-bimodules) if and only if $i=j$. But I don't know if this will be useful.

Comment: Do you have examples where it is simple? I am a bit lost about where you got the inspiration for this.

Comment: I'm thinking about something like this... take a field F and a field automorphism $\sigma : F \to F$ of infinite order and consider the skew polynomial ring $F[x,x^{-1}]$ where the multiplication is defined by $(ax^n)(bx^m)=a\sigma^n(b)x^{n+m}$. Then $M=F[x,x^{-1}]$ and $I$ is the set of integers, with $N_i = Fx^i$ for $i\in I$. And I believe that $M$ has the above properties. To me it makes sense for $F$ (or $R$) to be simple, but I am not able to prove that it is a necessary condition.

Comment: Your example is interesting, but my question was : do you have instances where you know that the result holds?

Comment: No, I don't know any class of examples where the question has an affirmative answer. And neither can I construct a counterexample.

Comment: Isn't it a bit of a longshot to try to prove something new where you have no examples of where it works? By the way, I was wondering what is the equivalence relation you put on the set of $R$-bisubmodules of $M$.

Comment: I agree, but if it is completely false, then I am hoping that someone can help me to build a counterexample. The equivalence relation is given by R-bimodule isomorphism.